# Problem using gtk with ROS

Tags: ros, catkin-make, include

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.

My problem is when I try to use `catkin_make`.

I have my `catkin_ws` in `/home/name-of-user/`, and inside of it has a `file.cpp`.
This `file.cpp` has an `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` in order to make a GUI with gtk.
The `gtk.h` path is `/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/`.

And here is the problem: When I use `catkin_make` it shows this error:

```
[ 75%] /home/name-of-user/catkin_ws/src/package/src/file.cpp:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
                     ^

compilation terminated.

make[2]: *** [package/CMakeFiles/file.dir/src/file.cpp.o] Error 1

make[1]: *** [package/CMakeFiles/package.dir/all] Error 2
...
make: *** [all] Error 2

Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I think maybe I have to write something in `CMakeLists.txt`, but I don't know what.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Here is the CMakeList.txt that I think I have to modify...

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(mov_autom)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  geometry_msgs
  kobuki_safety_controller
  roscpp
  turtlebot_bringup
  yocs_velocity_smoother
)

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(randommov src/randommov.cpp)
target_link_libraries(randommov ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(randommov ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

add_executable(randomlaser src/randomlaser.cpp)
target_link_libraries(randomlaser ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(randomlaser ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

add_executable(listenermov src/listenermov.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listenermov ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(listenermov ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

add_executable(interfaz_mejorada src/interfaz_mejorada.cpp)
target_link_libraries(interfaz_mejorada ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(interfaz_mejorada ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226113/problem-using-gtk-with-ros/) by [Adri](https://answers.ros.org/users/25773/adri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-02-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-02-09**:
Please edit your question, pasting in the part of your CMakeLists.txt that finds the gtk headers. See: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/system_library_dependencies.html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You forgot to resolve your system library dependency on gtk.

See: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/system_library_dependencies.html

You'll need some kind of `find_package()` for gtk, then add the header path it returns on your `include_directories()` invocation. (You only need one of those, you call it twice right now.)

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1